# Should we generalize the [native-code] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

Until now, we have been using the [native-code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/native-code) tag for questions involving high-level code that calls [c](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c), [c++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), or similar lower-level code.

Occasionally, people write code to allow [c](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c) or [c++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) code to call code in a higher-level language, perhaps in an embedded interpreter.  In that case, using the [native-code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/native-code) tag feels wrong, since we're going in the opposite direction.  The best way to tag such questions, I believe is [ffi](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ffi), a tag that I have just created.  A [foreign function interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_function_interface) is a mechanism by which a program written in one programming language can call routines or make use of services written in another.

If we have a [ffi](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ffi) tag, though, then [native-code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/native-code) is just a special case of FFI, right?  Whether high-level code calls low-level code or *vice versa*, it's a similar topic and skillset, I think.  Should we rename [native-code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/native-code) to [ffi](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ffi) for generality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A bit convoluted but I got there in the end.

1. To maintain tag history I:
   Merged [ffi](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ffi) into [native-code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/native-code).
2. Since there seems to be no rename tool I:
   Merged [native-code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/native-code) into [ffi](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ffi), with synonym.
3. For improved tag SEO I:
   Made [foreign-function-interface](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/foreign-function-interface) synonym to [ffi](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ffi).